# Create test table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I create a table with `x attributes` and `n rows like`?

For example:

```
x = 4 , and n = 10


att1  att2  att3  att4
----------------------
1       2     3     4
1       2     3     4
1       2     3     4
1       2     3     4
1       2     3     4
1       2     3     4
1       2     3     4
1       2     3     4
1       2     3     4
1       2     3     4
```

Comment: Can you only use SSMS or can a script/app be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @x int = 4, @n int = 10
declare @strg nvarchar(1000) = 'create table myTable ('
declare @i int = 1

while @i<= @x
begin
    set @strg = @strg + 'att' + cast(@i as varchar(5))+ ' int default ' + CAST(@i as varchar(5)) + ','
    set @i = @i + 1
end

set @strg = SUBSTRING(@strg, 1, LEN(@strg)-1) + ')'
-- this creates your table
exec sp_executesql @strg


-- now lets insert rows
set @i = 0

while @i < @n
begin
    INSERT INTO myTable DEFAULT VALUES;
    set @i = @i + 1
end

-- lets check
select *
from myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script. You could put this into a stored procedure or just leave it as it is. All you have to do is update the initial col and row values.

```
DECLARE
@cols INT = 4,
@rows INT = 10,
@tablename VARCHAR(20) = 'TestTable'


DECLARE
@i INT = 1,
@j INT = 1,
@sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'create table ' + @tablename + '('

WHILE(@i <= @cols)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + 'att' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' VARCHAR(10)'
    IF NOT @i = @cols
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + ', '
    END
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SET @sql = @sql + ')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tablename + ' VALUES'

WHILE(@j <= @rows)
BEGIN
    SET @i = 1
    SET @sql = @sql + '('
    WHILE(@i <= @cols)
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '''' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(10)) + ''''
        IF NOT @i = @cols
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + ', '
        END
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
    IF NOT @j = @rows
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '), '
    END
    SET @j = @j + 1
END

SET @sql = @sql + ')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Hope this helps.